# Simple ASP.NET Core routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

using the following

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "beacon",
       template: "beacon/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

`http://www.example.com/beacon` does what I expect and hits `BeaconController`

But `http://www.example.com/beacon/001` does not hit any controller and goes 404

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an `Index` action method inside BeaconController accepting an input `id` parameter of type integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified the route pattern URL, but did not mention what controller/action should handle these type of requests.

You may specify the defaults options when defining the route

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "beacon",
      template: "beacon/{id?}", 
      defaults: new { controller = "Beacon", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Assuming your `Index` method has a `id` parameter of nullable int type

```
public class BeaconController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if(id!=null)
        {
            return Content(id.Value.ToString());
        }
        return Content("Id missing");    
    }
}
```

Another option is to remove the specific route definition from the `UseMvc` method and specify it using attribute routing.

```
public class BeaconController : Controller
{
    [Route("Beacon/{id?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if(id!=null)
        {
            return Content(id.Value.ToString());
        }
        return Content("Id missing");
    }
}
```

The reason, `http://www.example.com/beacon` is working is because that request structure matches to the pattern defined for the default route.

Comment: Yes - specify the name of the controller in the defaults. Just naming the route does not hook it to the proper controller. I'm learning - thanks Shyju!